# How can I fix when logging out from user page I am getting logged out from admin page aswell?

Tags: php

I am creating a website with user login and admin login  but the problem is when I logout  if I logout from user page or admin page it logouts from the other page too  the reason is because when I logout I use `session_destroy()`but how can I fix this problem  should I do something else instead of `session_destroy()` ?

Comment: Share your code here. But as a general rule, running `session_destroy` will log out of anything on that domain.

Comment: The answer to the question is YES

Comment: If you show us your code, you will always get a better response from the community, and maybe even some useful answers

Comment: Why are these two different logins in the first place? Usually such systems work in a way that there is _one_ login, but users can have different roles or capabilities.

Comment: @misorude thanks for the idea I am gonna use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `unset($_SESSION['your_page_session_id']);` function to destroy only the ID from your page at the logout. With a destroy you 'destroy' 
 data there stored on the server session.

> `session_destroy()` removes session data stored on the server for that session id and requests the client to delete that cookie, however to save performance this is done routinely and not immediately.

The [doc handbook](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php) describe more details.

Answer (score 2):

you can use two variables for user and admin 
for example:

```
$_SESSION['user_login']=TRUE;
$_SESSION['admin_login']=FALSE;
```

check user or admin :

```
if($_SESSION['user_login']){...}
if($_SESSION['admin_login']){...}
```